# Using .htaccess with dynamic folders - wordpress

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have this .htaccess file in the root of my wordpress site.

```
RewriteEngine on

#For the spanish language, redirect to the spanish translation
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^es [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ %{REQUEST_URI}es/ [L,R=301]

#For every other language (including English) use English(the default)
RewriteRule ^$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=301] #can remove this i know
```

This is working fine for the root of the site. e.g www.mysite.com, if the user's browser language has spanish default, it will redirect to www.mysite.com/es/

However, if the user clicks another link to www.mysite.com/help/, it does not load the help page in spanish - expected it to load automatically, www.mysite.com/help/es/

Note:

1. I cannot put .htaccess in all sub folders - they are dynamically generated. (or i don't know how to)
2. I have tried putting these settings in /etc/apache2/apache2.conf in the  . It still does not help.
3. I need to avoid infinite loops

How do i make this happen?

This is the complete mod_rewrite part, after the first answer

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^assets/css/(.*) /wp-content/themes/mytheme/assets/css/$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^assets/js/(.*) /wp-content/themes/mytheme/assets/js/$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^assets/img/(.*) /wp-content/themes/mytheme/assets/img/$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^plugins/(.*) /wp-content/plugins/$1 [QSA,L]

#For the spanish language, redirect to the spanish translation
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^es [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !es [NC]
RewriteRule .? /es%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: `^$` does not allow anything after `www.mysite.com/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
RewriteEngine on


#For the spanish language, redirect to the spanish translation
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^es [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !es [NC]
RewriteRule .? %{REQUEST_URI}es/ [L,R=301]
```

Comment: This works great for such links as www.mysite.com/ www.mysite.com/page1, www.mysite.com/page2, etc. However, how to i handle www.mysite.com/page1/subpage2 also ?

Comment: This RewriteRule should to the job: `RewriteRule .? %{REQUEST_URI}/es [L,R=301]` Just replace the old one.

Comment: Actually, thanks , it does. However, i notice some images disappear when i use it. Is it possible that it is rewriting also such things as <img src="/assests/image.jpg" ... />

Comment: Please try it with pages that have been marked as having a parent in wordpress page attributes. Does not work

Comment: Testing with `www.mysite.com/page1/subpage2` sends me in `www.mysite.com/page1/subpage2/es` like it should. In order for your images to not dissapear, you must use full path, not a relative one.

Comment: In this case subpage2 has been marked as having a parent through wordpress page attributes?

Comment: @Telewa:Why you're appending your translation before the URL? I believe `RewriteRule .? /es%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]` should be `RewriteRule .? %{REQUEST_URI}es/ [L,R=301]` It was you defined this in your question by `expected it to load automatically, www.mysite.com/help/es/`

Comment: Also, asking a question, receiving an answer, marking as answer and then changing your question in a way which the answer is not longer an answer is a waste of time on both sides, and not the way SO works. Avoid doing that.

Comment: well, I fixed the problem using your code. i just modified it to suit my needs. About the pages marked as having a parent, i just removed the parent-child relationship of the pages, which does not affect my menu system anyway, then saved. Then using the code in the answer above, all the pages get translated just fine.  Thanks for the help